# Freemarker css not working for html rendered from backend

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, freemarker

I have a springboot application which has an endpoint which would load a freemarker template(abc.ftlh). It looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
        .topRight {
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            right:0;
        }
        .data-body {
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            background-color: #f7f7f7
        }
        .option, .span {
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        .p {
            font-weight: 300;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #333333;
            line-height: 1.22;
        }
        .h1, .h2 {
            font-weight:normal;
            font-size: 18px
        }
        .h3 {
            color: #9b9b9b;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 300;
            line-height: 1.22;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="data-body">
<br /><br />
<div class="topRight">
    
</div>

<div>
    ${databody}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the variable databody is being set from the backend. It has content like

```
<h1>Something</h1>

<h2>foo bar</h2>
```

css is applied to elements which are present in the template for example `data-body` and `topRight` is applied. But css is not applied for the elements which are rendered from backend. For example `<h1>`,  `<h2>` are not applied.

How can I get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues here.
The css for html tags should be named without the preceding dot.
For example `.h1` should be `h1`

Most important thing here is to tell freemarker to not not escape the value. By default auto escaping is enabled.

If the string value to print deliberately contains markup, auto-escaping must be prevented like `${value?no_esc}`.

So the solution here is `${databody}` should be `${databody?no_esc}`

More on this topic here https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_quickstart_template.html#dgui_quickstart_template_autoescaping

Answer (score 1):

It's simply because in your css you have `.h1` instead of just `h1`, etc. The `.h2` selector matches `<... class="h1">`, not `<h1>` itself.

Also, in CSS issues it never matters if something was generated by FreeMarker or not, as the browser can't tell the difference.

Comment: I tried with h1(removing the preceding dot) as well. Did not work

Answer (score 0):

`.h1` means that you want to select all `class="h1"` elements.

```css
     .h1, .h2 {
            font-weight:normal;
            font-size: 18px
        }
        .h3 {
            color: #9b9b9b;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 300;
            line-height: 1.22;
        }
```

You can select the `<h1>` directly and apply css to it via `h1{...}`

---

It would be easier if you place these css files under `resouce/static` folder, and reference in the HTML head.